# How do I capture user information when the PayPal button is clicked?

Tags: php, html, forms, button, paypal

I have a form were a user enters information, and then I have a PayPal button that the user will click once the fields have been filled in. The problem I'm having is how to you capture the user information when the paypal button is clicked, if the form has `action="http://paypl.com/something/something"`.

Do I have to make this a 2 page process - one for me to capture the user information and then one to have the user click the paypal button?

By the way - the PayPal button directs the user to paypal.com to actually make the payment.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to facilitate a scenario that the paypal standard api is not meant for.  You will not reliably be able to capture this information as the client can cancel once they are on the paypal site and you will not be notified.  Both of the solutions below will leave you with possibly incorrect information in your database. If you need full integration you need to look at the paypal pro flow api - the cost is aprox $30 per month.

Comment: @Doug: Or, he can use an IPN script and avoid the monthly fee.

Comment: See my comment.  It takes searching, but PayPal has accommodated exactly these type of scenarios.  They just don't document it.  Heck, they don't document much of anything in plain English.....

Comment: @Josh - I was not aware of the IPN callback - So yes it appears you can bypass the $30 fee as long as you don't mind your clients  navigating away from your site to paypal. Thanks for the additional important information Josh!

Comment: @bpeterson76 - totally agree with you on the poorly documented api comment!!

Comment: Catfish, did we answer your question?

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try your solution yet. I'll let you know when i do. Thanks for your help thus far.

Answer (score 6):

Guys, there's an easier solution here.  Paypal allows you to pass those values through to it, then it will spit them back to you.  There's actually two methods of getting the data back--a return URL that posts upon completion with return values (I've not been terribly lucky making that work) then a separate function that sends you a post upon completion of a transaction to a separate page on your site, where you can collect back all the variables you posted to the site.  I suggest the latter because on a buy it now page there's a possibility of the user not being returned to the site because the return button UI is pretty weak on PayPal's end.

To set it up you'd log in to your PayPal account, click on myaccount > profile > website payment preferences.  Enabling the "payment data transfer" will do the trick.  Once you've got it setup correctly, upon completion of a transaction it'll send to the page of your choice a post of everything you sent it....remember, you can send in variables such as Name, Address, etc just by defining them properly in the form.  All the variables available are found [here](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables)

Sure, you could go through grabbing the elements from the form via Jquery or the like, then do an onclick save to DB, but why fight it?  It's a heck of a lot more work and may have issues if Javascript is off.

Don't forget to build a sandbox site to test!  Good Luck.

Comment: I thought there was something like that also, but to be honest I didn't bother re-reading the PayPal docs. Good answer.

Answer (score 3):

You have a few options here. You could make two forms, one which submits to your server where you capture the user information, and then display a second form with a "Pay Now" button. As a second option, you could extract the information from the form using JavaScript and submit it to your server using AJAX, then submit the form to PayPal when the AJAX request completes. This may or may not be more complicated, but it will not alter the existing user interface, which may be desirable.

Comment: I thought about ajax but i thought there had to be a better way. I'm going to try ClarkeyBoy's solution.

Comment: His solution may very well work. I forget off the top of my head if PayPal requires a POST or not

Answer (score 3):

I would make the action the current page, catch the button click and store the user information, then use `header: Location("http://paypl.com/something/something");`. Its something like that anyway. Hope this helps.

Edit: Also see the other answer by Josh. They are equally good possibilities. Note that the Ajax option would require JavaScript to be switched on - so safeguards would have to be put in place in case it is switched off.

Comment: I can't believe i didn't think of this.

Comment: Dont worry - everyone misses obvious things from time to time. It often takes multiple people to find the best solutions - hence sites like Facebook are developed by multiple people!

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to add all of your user/order data into your own local database so that you can generate an order ID of some kind.  You can then pass this order ID into your PayPal button code in a field named invoice.

This value will then come back in PDT/IPN as $_POST['invoice'] so you can easily pull all of that data back out and handle it within your application accordingly.

Another alternative would be to use Express Checkout instead of Payments Standard.  It's a little bit more involved, but it has fewer limitations.

Even with EC, though, I still recommend sending an order ID of some sort along with the payment request so you can relate everything back and forth easily.